# How to set sample format when using sox with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, libsox

I am trying to convert a 44.1k 16bit flac file into 48k 32 bit (float) wav file.

This is the command I use:

'ffmpeg -i in.flac -af aresample=resampler=soxr:precision=28:out_sample_fmt=fltp:out_sample_rate=48000 out.wav'

No matter which value I use for `out_sample_fmt` like `s32, flt, fltp` the output `out.wav` is only 16 bit.

What am I doing wrong here? How to get the highest quality (as in resampling) 32 bit floating point wav file with `ffmpeg` using `soxr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with soxr or aresample. Typically, after media data is filtered, it is encoded before being written to output. For each output format, there is a default encoder designated for each type of stream (audio, video..). In case of WAV, it's `pcm_s16le` for audio.

Add `-c:a pcm_f32le` for 32-bit floating point PCM, in little-endian order. Change `le` to `be` for big-endian.